# Error: 'Couldn't determine a writable folder where to store realm file'

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, realm

I am getting the `InvalidOperationException: couldn't determine a writable folder where to store realm file`.

I am creating a Unity game, using the Unity SDK for Realm, where I am building it for Android and iOS. The error occurs building it onto my Samsung S8, whilst the Unity editor works perfectly fine, saving into locallow, and iOS I have yet to test.

I have tried multiple combinations of the functions `Realm realm = Realm.GetInstance()`, with, and without parameters, along with the addition of a `RealmConfiguration`, also with, and without taking parameters. `Application.persistentDataPath`, `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal)`, `RealmConfiguration.DefaultConfiguration.DatabasePath`, leaving it blank, and various other paths I have tried have all failed to work, all giving the same error.

I am finding it quite weird how this error seems to be nearly non existent on the Internet other than two GitHub issues which haven't helped at all. Does anyone have any suggestions of what could be causing this?

e.g.

```
...
private void Start(){
     RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration(Application.persistentDataPath);
     realm = Realm.GetInstance(config);
...
}
```

After testing on IOS, I had the same error appear

Comment: Hi Ben, as I wrote already in the answer to your forum post: more info are needed for us to be able to help you.

Comment: Hi Ben, is this the same problem you discussed in https://github.com/realm/realm-dotnet/issues/1532 ? Did this solve it?